# How check name already exist using express validatator in update calls

Tags: express-validator

I have to check the name is already exist in database before adding the values.

So, I have decided to add express validator custom option. This is working fine in create call. But not working in update call. Here is my code

const { check, body } = require('express-validator/check');
var models = require("../models");

```
let Validations = [
    check('email').isEmail().withMessage("Invalid Email"),
    check('phone').isLength({ min: 5 }).withMessage("Min length Required"),
    check('name').not().isEmpty().withMessage("Value is Required"),
    body("name").custom(value => {
        return models.fundraisers.findByName(value).then(user => {
        if (user) {
            return Promise.reject('Name already in use');
        }
        })
    })
]
```

How to handle this in update calls.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is my check and it worked well at create and update case :

```
check('name')
  .not().isEmpty()
  .isString()
  .custom(value => {
    return Group
      .findByName(value)
      .then(groups => {
        if(groups.length > 0) {
          return Promise.reject(value + '\'s already in use');
        }
      })
  })
```

By the way, I defined only body-check :

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');
```

Hope it helps :)